# Find free port not in use for apps - find some algorithm

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, random, port

I use the following API in my program to detrmine free port and provide it to application to run

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(3000, 65000, '127.0.0.1', function(error, port) {
  console.log('AVAILABLE PORT AT: ' + port)
})
```

https://github.com/baalexander/node-portscanner

This free port are given to application for use and working OK.
The problem is that if I provide a free port to `application A` and the application is doesn't occupied it yet(sometimes it takes some time...) and there is coming other `application B` and request a free port so it give to **APP B the port of app A**
Which cause to problem...
is there any elegant way to solve it?

my application doesn't have state so it cannot save to which app get which port...

There is solution  that we can randomize the range but this is not robust ...

In my application Im getting the URL of the app that I should provide the free port to run.

**update**

I **cannot** use some broker or someting else that will controll this outside I need to find some **algorithm** (maybe with some smart random ) that can help me to do it internally i.e. my program is like singleton and I need some trick how to give port between `50000 to 65000` that will **reduce the amount of collision** of port that was provided to the apps

**update 2**

I've decided to try something like the following what do you think ?

using lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#random to determine ports between with loops that provide 3(or more if that make sense) numbers for ranges like following

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse([50001, 60000, 600010], '127.0.0.1', function(err, port) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("error!!!-> " +err);
    }else {
        console.log('Port Not in Use ' + port);
    }

//using that in a loop 
var aa = _.random(50000, 65000);
```

Then If I got false in the port i.e. all 3 port are occupied ,run this process again for 3 other random number.comments suggestion are welcomed!!!
**I try to find some way to avoid collision as much as possible**...

Comment: keep port of app A opens as long as app A did not open it by itself. Or use a broker service to assign port more safely.

Comment: @mh-cbon - 1. how can you please provide example ? 2 . if I change it to open when app A want to use it there will no error /problem?

Comment: @RaynD, is there any particular reason to not let the OS assign random port number at the time of calling `listen()` and report port just then?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek - we think about it but we cannot do it since we need to update some internal env before. so we cannot do it....

Answer (score 3):

I would simply accept the fact that things can go wrong in a distributed system and retry the operation (i.e., getting a free port) if it failed for whatever reason on the first attempt.

Luckily, there are lots of npm modules out there that do that already for you, e.g. [retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry).

Using this module you can retry an asynchronous operation until it succeeds, and configure waiting strategies, and how many times it should be retried maximally, and so on…

To provide a code example, it basically comes down to something such as:

```
const operation = retry.operation();

operation.attempt(currentAttempt => {
  findAnUnusedPortAndUseIt(err => {
    if (operation.retry(err)) {
      return;
    }

    callback(err ? operation.mainError() : null);
  });
});
```

The benefits of this solution are:

- Works without locking, i.e. it is efficient and makes low usage of resources if everything is fine.
- Works without a central broker or something like that.
- Works for distributed systems of any size.
- Uses a pattern that you can re-use in distributed systems for all kinds of problems.
- Uses a battle-tested and solid npm module instead of handwriting all these things.
- Does not require you to change your code in a major way, instead it is just adding a few lines.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

When managing multiple applications or multiple servers, where one must be right the first time (without retrying), you need a single source of truth. Applications on the same machine can talk to a database, a broker server or even a file, so long as the resource is "lockable". (Servers work in similar ways, though not with local files).

So your flow would be something like:

1. App A sends request to service to request lock.
2. When lock is confirmed, start port scanner
3. When port is used, release lock.

Again, this could be a "PortService" you write that hands out unused ports, or a simple lock in some shared resource so two things are getting the same port at the same time.

Hopefully you can find something suitable to work for your apps.

Comment: Yes this is make sense but unfortiontly I cannot use this approach , I need somehow to handle it internally , i've the request app url so maybe I can put hash to it by generate some hash mechanism that can provide range like randomize but more safe...

Comment: What do you mean by "internally"? Are these apps on the same machine? From what I understand of your question, they need a way to coordinate somehow.

Comment: I mean that I cannot use broker etc I my program is singleton and I need some algorithm that can  reduce the amount of collision,please see my update...

Comment: @RaynD Well, from withing the app, you can handle `EADDRINUSE` error and keep searching for new port until you get it.

Comment: @S.D. - the issue here that the application is getting this error after it try to listen to the provided port and it's too late...I need somehow to give port with with diffrent range every time to reduce the option to collision,any idea how ?

Comment: @RaynD Exactly what I am suggesting. Its similar to try inserting a unique id in db and re-trying again with new id if previous already exists.

Comment: @clay have you considered a simple hashing? It might be the best way to reduce the probability of a collision.

Comment: "When managing multiple applications or multiple servers, you need a single source of truth. " … this is just plain wrong.

Comment: Please explain @GoloRoden. How would multiple and independent things agree?

Comment: I updated my answer slightly, just to say the intent was to be correct the first time. Why "truth" was needed, rather than guessing and gracefully failing/retrying.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you look for a way to retain state. Even temporary state, in memory, is better than nothing at all. This way you could at least avoid giving out ports you've already given out. Because those are very likely not free anymore. (This would be as simple as saving them and regenerating a random port if you notice you found a random port you've already given out). If you don't want collisions, build your module to have state so it can avoid them. If you don't want to do that, you'll have to accept there are going to be collisions sometimes when there don't need to be.

If the URLs you get are random, the best you can do is guess randomly. If you can derive some property in which the URLs uniquely and consistently differ, you could design something around that.

Code example:

```
function getUnusedPort(url) {
  // range is [0, 65001). (inclusive zero, exclusive 65001)
  const guessPort = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 15001) + 50000;
  let randomPort = guessPort();
  while (checkPortInUse(randomPort)) {
    randomPort = guessPort();
  }
  return randomPort;
}
```

Notes:

- `checkPortInUse` will probably be asynchronous so you'll have to
  accommodate for that.
- You said 'between 50000 and 65000'. This is from 50000 up to and including 65000.

Comment: HI Alex , I think that the random seed can be an option , can you please provide code example how should I use it with the code in my post ...portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(50000, 65000, ...

Comment: I guess it should every time give other range between the 50000 - 65000 and try to find free port there if yes proceed if not try again with diffrent range. how does it sounds? any idea how to use the random-seed with it ?

Comment: @RaynD added a code example. I have to note, again, having shared state is preferable. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm revising my answer. After some more thinking and reading about this pseudo random generator I suggested I realize it doesn't improve anything at all. You cannot avoid collision without using state. The only way you could do it with url as the only piece of state you practically have is if you can intelligently reason about the url's you will get. For example if you know each URL will have a unique length you can base your choice around that. If you say the URLs are random, naturally our guessing also can't be better than random.

Answer (score 0):

If your applications can open ports with option like SO_REUSEADDR, but operation system keeps ports in the list in TIME_WAIT state, you can bind/open port you want to return with SO_REUSEADDR, instantly close it and give it back to application. So for TIME_WAIT period (depending on operation system it can be 30 seconds, and actual time should be decided/set up or found by experiment/administration) port list will show this port as occupied.

If your port finder does not give port numbers for ports in TIME_WAIT state, problem solved by relatively expensive open/close socket operation.

Comment: Thanks but not sure I got how to implement it... can you provide a code example ?

Answer (score -1):

As you want to find an port that is not in use in your application, you could do is run following command:

```
netstat -tupln | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d ':' -f2
```

so in your application you will use this like:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('netstat -tupln | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d ':' -f2', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  var listPorts = stdout.split(/\n/)
  console.log(listPorts); // list of all ports already in use
  var aa = _.random(50000, 65000); // generate random port
  var isFree = (listPorts.indexOf(aa)===-1) ? true : false;
  if(isFree){
          //start your appliation         
  }else{
         // restart the search, write this in a function and start search again 
  } 

});
```

this should give you list of all ports that are in use,so use any port except ones in the `listPorts`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but not sure how does it help me since the API (portscanner.findAPortNotInUse...) which I use I guess already done this internally...maybe I miss you point can you please elaborate ?

Comment: From what i understand from your question, Your problem is that application should start on different ports. so using this you can just check if the port your are trying to start is free or not, if you find the port in the list then it is already occupied.

Comment: so i guess when ever you generate a random port you could just check in the list if it exists, if it does ignore if not use. Isn't this what you are looking for?