# Jest initialize and shared objects once per test suite and across test cases

Tags: jestjs

I want to use shared resources between jest test suites. I read in  the internet and found that [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) could be the solution. But the `setup` is invoked per each test file.

I have two test files `links.test.js` and 'subscritpions.test.js'. I usually call them with one command `jest` and that all.

The problem is that the `setup` function of my custom environment `custom-environment.js`:

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

const MySql = require('../../lib/databases/myslq/db');

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config)
    }

    async setup() {
        await super.setup();
        console.log(`Global Setup  !!!!!!!!!`);
        this.global.gObject = "I am global object"
        this.global.liveUsers = await new MySql("Live Users");
        this.global.stageUsers = await new MySql("Stage Users");
    }

    async teardown() {
        console.log(`Global  terdown  !!!!!!!!!`);
        await super.teardown();
        this.global.gObject = "I am destroyed";
        this.global.liveUsers.closeConnection();
        this.global.stageUsers.closeConnection();
    }

    runScript(script) {
        return super.runScript(script)
    }

 }

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```

is called twice for each test:

> Global Setup  !!!!!!!!!
> Global Setup  !!!!!!!!!
> ERROR>>> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:3306

So it tries to establish second connection to the same port - while I could simply use the existing connection.

The way it works seems to me makes no difference from defining

```
beforeAll(async () => {
});
afterAll(() => {
});
```

hooks.

So to wrap up, the question is: Using `jest` command (thus running all test suits), how can I invoke setup function once for all test and share global objects across them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setup` and `teardown` are indeed executed for each test suite, similarly to top-level `beforeAll` and `afterAll`.

Test suites run in separate processes. Test environment is initialized for each test suite, e.g. `jsdom` environment provides fake DOM instance for each suite and cannot be cross-contaminated between them.

As the documentation states,

> Note: TestEnvironment is sandboxed. Each test suite will trigger setup/teardown in their own TestEnvironment.

The environment isn't suitable for global setup and teardown. [`globalSetup` and `globalTeardown`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string) should be used for that. They are appropriate for setting up and shutting down server instances, this is what documentation example shows:

```
// setup.js
module.exports = async () => {
  // ...
  // Set reference to mongod in order to close the server during teardown.
  global.__MONGOD__ = mongod;
};

// teardown.js
module.exports = async function () {
  await global.__MONGOD__.stop();
};
```

Since this happens in parent process, `__MONGOD__` is unavailable in test suites.

Comment: I prepared two files `setup.js` and `teardown.js` and added them in jest.config but they are not invoked.

Comment: and this `Note: Any global variables that are defined through globalSetup can only be read in globalTeardown. You cannot retrieve globals defined here in your test suites.`

Comment: I don't see how they cannot be invoked if you did everything correctly, try to `throw` there to see if they really aren't. As for *invoke setup function once for all test and share global objects across them* - these requirements are incompatible, the answer explains why.

Comment: You can use `runInBand` option and suite setup/teardown (either with custom environment or beforeAll/afterAll via `setupFilesAfterEnv`) if you need to keep single DB connection. This may slow down tests and I'm not sure if this is necessary in your case. The error means that you try to listen to a server simultaneously. If you can afford multiple DB connections, you could start only 1 server with global setup/teardown and create a connection per each suite. This mostly depends on how you handle DB.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/41095195/5598574 i use as workaround. I open multiple local ports for each connection. I try different ports until success