# "top level" test in jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

While writing integration tests in jest I would like to reproduce the same behaviour I have achieved in mocha by:
`mocha -r ts-node/register tests/integration/topLevelTest.test.ts 'tests/integration/**/*.test.ts'`.

topLevelTest.test.ts :

```ts
let importantVariable;

describe("should do something with my variable", () => {
  importantVariable = returnSomethingImportant();

  it("should important variable exists", () => {
    should.exist(importantVariable)
  })
})

after(() => {
  importantVariable.cleanUp()
})
```

Behaviour was simple: firstly topLevelTest executed describe, then other test suites executed themselves, and in the end *after* within topLevelTest were executed.

In my attempt of rewriting it to jest I wrote something very similar. Only difference is I used *afterAll* instead of *after*. The result is: firstly topLevelTest executed describe, then *afterAll*, and then other test suites. Is it possible to make afterAll run after other test suites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what setup files are for, more specifically [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) because Jest environment is already initialized there with globals being available.

Top-level `afterAll` that wasn't grouped with `describe` applies to all tests within current test suite. Since Jest tests run in parallel (unless `runInBand` option was specified) in different threads, it obviously won't affect other test suites.

In case tests need to not proceed if a setup failed and data from setup needs to not be, `globalSetup` and globalTeardown configuration options should be used for that. This is not a test but the main difference is that `describe` and separate `test` blocks are unavailable. Global expect is not available but can be imported, this results in meaningful errors in case a setup fails:

```
// setup.js
let expect = require('expect');
module.exports = async () => {
  let server = ...;
  expect(server)...;
  global.__MYSERVER__ = server;
};

// teardown.js
module.exports = async function () {
  // close __MYSERVER__
};
```

Since global setup and teardown run in parent process, `__MYSERVER__` cannot be accessed in tests.

Comment: the problem with this approach is I would like to test once if my importantVariable has been properly defined and after all test suites properly cleaned up. Using it with setupFilesAfterEnv will additionally needlessly log many other same importantVariable tests ("should do something with my variable" and "should important variable exists" in example)

Comment: The question lacks the context. What is importantVariable and how is it used? The way this can be done depends on it.

Comment: by returnSomethingImportant()  I'm forking a src/ in a different process, which sets up my nodejs server, then set up listener to importantVariable, which waits for a specific log within that process ("Server started") and then test passes ("should important variable exists" in example). In afterAll I simply kill that process so I need reference to it.

Comment: setupFilesAfterEnv before/afterAll run for every test file. They run simultaneously in child processes which is one of major Jest benefits, so expecting that a test that will run once before all tests doesn't make sense from Jest perspective (unless you use runInBand which should be used as the last resort).

Comment: If you don't need to share importantVariable with tests and keep it just for a cleanup then you can set up the server and shut it down once in parent process before tests start, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62609902/3731501 . This won't be a test because Jest environment isn't available there but you need to assert with the same syntax as in tests, use `require('expect')` instead of global `expect`.